# MySQL Architecture Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-design

I have tried out two approaches but I can't decide which one would do better generally as the size of input increases.

First the back story:

We have products, and each product has a category path (e.g. Accessories-shoes-sneakers)

I want to connect my products with their respective categories whilst keeping things compatible with the 3NF rules.

I can go about this two ways, I could:

1. Have a many to many relationship between products and categories (by blowing up the category path into individual categories and forming an association in a many to many table)

   Pros:
   Simple and easy to understand.

   Cons:
   The many-many association grows exponentially! You can imagine why, each product has multiple categories and the test case involved just 250,000 products. I can intuitively see that as the size of input increases the stress on the databases engine will increase.
2. Create a Many to Many relationship between categories paths and products and another many to many relationship between category paths and the actual categories. This makes sense to me since the categories paths in a test case of 250,000 products are limited to 13,000 unique instances and these paths associated with their actual categories in another many to many relationship don't exceed more than 61,000 rows.

   Pros:
   Far fewer category associations for the database to swift through (61,000 associations as compared to 900,000 associations formed in the first technique)

   Cons:
   Far more inner joins. Products are connected to category paths, which are in turn connected with categories in a many to many relation ship.

Which of these techniques do you think would be more suitable? I need FAST retrievals, therefore fast select statements should be the main criteria.

I realize that  lot of this depends on proper indexing, but in the first scenario the size of rows grows by a factor of 3 at the very least where as in the second scenario there are so many inner joins that I fear the speed of retrieval is being negatively affected.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have tried both ways out. It turns out the second technique is much faster. The mapping table between products and categories inevitably returns ten times more rows than a mapping table between category_path and categories connected to the products table by storing the corresponding category path for each product.

It is simple Math really. Moral of the story: Maintain a Dictionary Table (Category_Path) along with its Definitions (Categories) And connect the dictionary table to each of the corresponding items (Products) through a foreign key. Far fewer rows makes everyone happy :)